# Charge Cap Crystal - Package

Tags: crystal

I got an external crystal for a MCU ( tm4c1233h6pm).

I use the NX-16MHZ from NDK, in the datasheet, the recommend cap charge for the crystal are 2 cap of 10 pF for a 16 Mhz crystal.

My question is that I used 0603 package for the caps in the first iteration, but if I change to a smaller package like 0402 can it leads to problem?

Comment: Have you properly accounted for the trace capacitance?

Comment: Although allowing for trace stray capacitance is technically a good idea, I have never seen an example where it becomes relevant. All oscillators I have seen are very tolerant and the crystal itself will not drift any more or less due to trace strays - it may just be fractionally off-tune.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The crystal datasheet say if you put the crystal under 6 mm up to 18 mm near your MCU, you shouldn't be concern with trace capacitance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be fine - don't give it a second thought. Do ensure that the capacitor is a C0G/NP0 type though.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the capacitance remains the same, just changing the package size shouldn't cause any unwanted effects.